# Cómo crear una lista de diccionarios en python

Tags: python

Estoy tratando de crear una lista de diccionarios en python, el código de ejemplo que estoy usando es este:

```
m = {}
b = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
f = []
for(l, n) in b.items():
    g = 6
    h = 7
    m['letter'] = l
    m['newnumbers'] = {}
    m['newnumbers']['g'] = g
    m['newnumbers']['h']= h
    f.append(m)
```

Cuando imprimo m lo que obtengo es

```
[{'letter': 'c', 'newnumbers':{'g':6, 'h':7}}, {'letter': 'c', 'newnumbers':{'g':6, 'h':7}},{'letter': 'c', 'newnumbers':{'g':6, 'h':7}}]
```

El resultado esperado es que actualize la llave letter. Cómo puedo lograr esto??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que estas haciendo es modificar el diccionario que introduces en la lista de diccionarios una vez introducido. Poniendo un print después del append puedes ver cual es el funcionamiento:

```
[{'newnumbers': {'h': 7, 'g': 6}, 'letter': ('a', 1)}]
[{'newnumbers': {'h': 7, 'g': 6}, 'letter': ('c', 3)}, {'newnumbers': {'h': 7, 'g': 6}, 'letter': ('c', 3)}]
[{'newnumbers': {'h': 7, 'g': 6}, 'letter': ('b', 2)}, {'newnumbers': {'h': 7, 'g': 6}, 'letter': ('b', 2)}, {'newnumbers': {'h': 7, 'g': 6}, 'letter': ('b', 2)}]
```

Esto ocurre porque introduces la variable m tres veces en la lista [m,m,m] y la modificas a lo largo del programa. Es por eso que ves tres copias de la variable m.

Lo que tienes que hacer es no modificar la variable que introduces en la lista de diccionarios, por ejemplo introduciendo una copia. Una posible solución:

```
m = {}
b = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
f = []
for (l, n) in b.items():
    g = 6
    h = 7
    m['letter'] = l
    m['newnumbers'] = {}
    m['newnumbers']['g'] = g
    m['newnumbers']['h']= h
    f.append(m.copy())
```

Devuelve:

```
[{'newnumbers': {'h': 7, 'g': 6}, 'letter': 'a'}, {'newnumbers': {'h': 7, 'g': 6}, 'letter': 'c'}, {'newnumbers': {'h': 7, 'g': 6}, 'letter': 'b'}]
```